# Flutter: Vertical Line between First letter of Text Widget Children in a ListView.builder()

Tags: flutter, material-ui

I want to recreate a UI like the one below where the first character of every Text widget of the children in a Listview is connected by a verticle line. If the Items of that ListView have sub Children vertical line should be joined by a horizontal line as the image.

[image: Sample Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily solve your problem by adding this module to the pubspec.yaml file.
https://pub.dev/packages/animated_tree_view

When you add above mentioned dependency then you will get output like below :

[image]

I hope I have helped. Enjoy your work.

Answer (score 1):

I've taken your image and added some lines to show you how you might think about breaking this UI down. See [this blog post](https://medium.com/flutter-community/thinking-flutter-22f38961f9ba) for more examples. I'll describe afterwards some more specific Widget choices.

[image: Image of a fast food basket mobile view, with lines separating different UI components]

First, you may break it down into rows inside a `ListView`. This is the main red lines. Perhaps you would group together the heading and subrows - e.g. "BLT Sandwich" and the "With Remove" and "Note" rows may be grouped under one widget.

Each row may then be split into three parts.

- The left most part will either be used for the quantity of that item, or to display the custom grey lines for the sub-rows. The custom grey lines could be built with some `Column` and `Divider` widgets, or maybe with a `CustomPaint` widget.
- The middle part will show the main content, either just some text or several grouped widgets in the case of "With Remove" and "Note" rows. These grouped ones could well be composed of `Row` and `Column` widgets.
- The right most part then is either empty or shows the price

Bear in mind this is just one option! Depending on what other formats of rows you have, and just personal choice, you could group different elements together differently.

How you group will make certain changes and design options easier or harder, but something like this should be pretty flexible :)